# Heavy issue here trying to upload data to a database

Tags: php, forms, session

I'm having a big issue here, I'm trying to upload some data to a database, and I really don't have a clue why it isn't getting uploaded.

This one here is my HTML form to send data to the php. (This one here should have no problem at all)

```
<form method="post" action="uploadinfo.php">
 <div style="width:542px;height:129px;margin-left:45px;margin-top:102px">
  <textarea name="stufftoupload" placeholder="Write your stuff here" rows="8" cols="65"></textarea>
 </div>
 <div style="width:95px;height:29px;margin-left:489px;margin-top:22px">
  <input type="image" src="myimg.png">
 </div>
</form>
```

And this one here is my PHP to upload to the database, this is where the problem should be, but I have no clue what it is. I've tried several solutions, but nothing is working.

```
<?php

 session_start();

 $db = mysql_connect("host","db","pass");
 if(!$db) die("Error");
 mysql_select_db("table",$db);

 $email = $_SESSION['email'];
 $stuff = $_POST['stuff'];

 if (!$stuff)
 {
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.alert('Fill all the blanks.')</script>"; 
  $url = 'upload.php';
  echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">'; 
 }
 else
 {
  $url = 'success.php';
  echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';    
 }

 mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE email = '$email'";
 $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

 mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

 $sql = "INSERT INTO table SET stuff = '$stuff'" or die(mysql_error());

 $result = mysql_query($sql);

?>
```

So this is about it, I'm almost positive it's something within this code, but it could be some bad session managing, though I'm not totally sure about it.

Anyway, thanks in advance for the help. It'll be totally appreciated.

Comment: For starters, you're mixing `mysql` and `mysqli` elements... Use `mysqli` as the former is depreciated.

Comment: And I'm fairly certain your SQL to INSERT is not correct.

Comment: We need to see original code. Don't modify it before posting here.

Comment: Have you tried enabling `error_reporting(E_ALL);` yet?

Answer (score 0):

`$db` is connecting to the database using the mysql method, but you are querying based on the mysqli methods. There are 2 things you need to do here to have an idea of what is going on. Firstly, change all your `mysql_` calls to `mysqli_` calls, and add some error reporting (so for example adding `or die (mysqli_error($db);` to the end of every line where you query) should point you in the right direction.

Your first glaring problem here is that you conneced to the DB using mysql_connect, but are then trying to query that connection using mysqli. Use one, not both.

Also, your SQL Query should read `INSERT INTO table (stuff) VALUES ($stuff)` rather than `INSERT INTO table SET stuff = '$stuff'`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was indeed stuff about mysqli, but also some misusage of sessions, it is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here so I'll start with what I see  now.

This line:

```
$db = mysql_connect("host","db","pass");
```

is what connects to your database and I'm assuming that "host" doesn't point to anything.  Depending on where that is running, normally Localhost is used.  You would also need to make sure the password is correct.

As suggested, use mysqli.

Your insert needs to be something like:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ({$stuff});
```

Not sure what you want from that form but your session variables will have to match the input names you use on the form.

```
$stuff = $_POST['stufftoupload'];
```